# Previous item.text of the Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, event-handling

I am using MS VS 2010, and working on an ASP.NET C# website.  I am stuck on something that I think may be quite simple, maybe not though.

Lets say I have a drop down list.

```
DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
ddl.ID = "d355";
dynamicPanel.Controls.Add(ddl);

ListItem lstItem1 = new ListItem();
lstItem1.Text = "1";
ListItem lstItem2 = new ListItem();
lstItem2.Text = "2";

ddl.Items.Add(lstItem1);
ddl.Items.Add(lstItem2);
ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Since we programatically created our drop down list, we need to also create our custom event handler that we tied to it.

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add the selected index to a counter
    counter +=((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
    // Now this is where I get stuck, if the current selected index is less
    // than the previous selected index, I want to subtract from the counter



}
```

This is where my problem lies.  Please read the comments in the event handler.  (Sorry if I have some of the syntax off, this is all free hand at the moment)

I have a feeling that I can get the previous selected index (or item it doesn't matter) from the event args ((DropDownList)e).?

Please help >.< This doesn't seem too bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that there is a built in mechanism, but you could use `ViewState` or a `HiddenField` to keep the previous index.
Something like the following:

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
        if (selectedIndex < (int)ViewState["PreviousIndex"])
        {
            counter -= ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
        }
        else
        {
            counter += ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedIndex;
        }
        // update the index
        ViewState["PreviousIndex"] = selectedIndex;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply.  Do you think it would be bad to create a ViewState / Session variable for each DDL? As I could create up to 30 throughout the whole process of the application.

Comment: You could combine them into a single dictionary model using one viewstate key.

Comment: I wouldn't create a Session variable cause it's not needed, but since you are only storing an int (index), I guess ViewState would be fine.

Comment: But don't forget to store the new SelectedIndex in the ViewState, otherwise this will only work once.

Comment: @Fischermaen ViewState has had me itching my head one or two times.  Thanks for the reminder.

@ Everyone, so you guys don't think its bad to have 30+ ViewState variables open. From my understanding, the viewstate is kind of like a hidden aspx page at the top of your page that gets parsed everyload.  If 30 is of no concern, does anyone know at what number we should start getting concerned.  Thanks!

Comment: @Fischermaen: I added the previous index update in the sample.

Comment: @misha I like your answer and will accept it soon.  Could you please let me know one thing really quick.  How come I should use ViewState opposed to a Session variable.  Thanks!

Comment: `ViewState` is "page local" and gets rendered to the client (thus no sensitive data, no big amounts). The `Session` state is "session local", thus multiple browser tabs or windows may share one. It might be stored in process memory or externally, in SQL server for instance. You may also consider storing pieces of information in a DB and use ASP.NET `Cache` (might scale better than an externally stored session state if you use multiple web servers).